# Oracle ODBC Driver connection failing from VB

Tags: vb.net

I tried to connect the Oracle 64 bit from VB using below code its failing while connecting to the DB. Is this required any configuration in Windows Machine?

```
gl_OraConn.Open "Driver={Oracle ODBC Driver};" & "Dbq=" & Trim(gs_OracleLogOnSrv) & ";" & _
                 "Uid=" & Trim(gs_OracleUser) & ";" & "Pwd=" & Trim(gs_OraclePass)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Do you have a tnsnames.ora?